# kestrel-dotnetapp.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/dotnet: Permission denied

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install .NET Core(3.1) app in Centos8 using steps given in MS [enter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1) .

Service File as per Microsoft document `/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-dotnetapp.service`

> [Unit]
>   Description= .NET Web API App for centos
>   
>   [Service]
>   WorkingDirectory=/var/Application/netcoreapp31
>   ExecStart=/usr/local/dotnet /var/Application/netcoreapp31/helloapp.dll
>   Restart=always
>     # Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
>   RestartSec=10
>   KillSignal=SIGINT
>   SyslogIdentifier=dotnetapp
>   User=user
>   Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
>   Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
>   
>   [Install]
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target

When i do > `sudo systemctl restart kestrel-dotnetapp.service` am getting error.

> Jun 04 22:51:28 hostname systemd[1827]: kestrel-dotnetapp.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
>   Jun 04 22:51:28 hostname systemd[1827]: kestrel-dotnetapp.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/dotnet: Permission denied
>   -- Subject: Process /usr/local/dotnet could not be executed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd

Find below **ls -la** :

```
[user@hostname dotnet]$ ls -la
total 108
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root    94 Apr 22 09:34 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root   154 Jun  4 21:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 73048 Apr 22 09:32 dotnet
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root    17 Apr 22 09:34 host
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1116 Apr 22 09:29 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root    67 Apr 22 09:34 shared
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 31330 Apr 22 09:29 ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

My application deliverables folder

```
[user@hostname Application]$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     26 Jun  4 20:53 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root   4096 Jun  4 20:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2  777 user 4096 Jun  4 20:45 netcoreapp31
```

Comment: You ran `ls -la` but you don’t tell us where it is.  Your unit says the executable is `/usr/local/dotnet`, but the `ls` output has a `dotnet` executable in it, and the directory name is “dotnet”. Are you sure you don’t mean to use `/usr/local/dotnet/dotnet ` as the executable in the ExecStart?

Comment: Hi @jsbillings 

dotnet is available in /usr/local/dotnet folder !!

i have ran `ls -la`  in `/usr/local/dotnet` . i tried putting `/usr/local/dotnet/dotnet` as executable Start even-though it wasn't in MS doc still nothing helped me

Comment: When you changed it to /usr/local/dotnet/dotnet, did the errors change?

Comment: @jsbillings it worked !!! after changing ExecStart to `/usr/local/dotnet/dotnet` and gave access with chmod 755, service started successfully 

i don't know why microsoft mentioned till ~/dotnet is enough though 

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution for redhat os usr/bin/dotnet permission denied.

1. `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet/dotnet`
2. Gave permission to service file like `chmod 755 your filename.service`
3. After gave permission execute below command

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable Your filename.service
   sudo systemctl start  Your filename.service  
   sudo systemctl status Your filename.service
   ```

Example for yourfilename: `abc.service`